# MYSQL commonly asked question to print '*' 20,19...1 times

Tags: mysql, loops, procedure

We got to print '*' 20 times followed by 19 times and so on till we only got to print 1!

```
delimiter $$
create procedure test()
begin
    set @ans = 20;
    while(@ans>0) do
        select repeat('*',@ans);
        set @ans = @ans - 1;
    end while;
end $$
delimiter ;

call test();
```

This is getting the job done but also printing `(repeat('*',@ans))` after each respective character line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want :

You can add the alias you want in this exemple its `*`

```
delimiter $$
create procedure test()
begin
    set @ans = 20;
    while(@ans>0) do
        select repeat('*',@ans) as '*';
        set @ans = @ans - 1;
    end while;
end $$
delimiter ;

call test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is performing a select statement 20 times and each select statement has its own *result-set*, so this is what causes what you said: *printing (repeat('*',@ans)) after each respective character line*.

Instead, you could use a variable to store the *populated strings* inside the while loop, then select that variable outside the loop.

```
create procedure test()
begin
    set @ans = 20;
    set @res = '';
    while(@ans>0) do
        set @res= concat(@res , repeat('*',@ans), '\n'); -- you may replace '\n' with any other delimiter.
        set @ans = @ans - 1;
    end while;
select @res as test_result;
end
```

[see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/o15ByZRE)